# Calling static methods

Tags: python, static, static-methods

How would I call a static method from another module/app (in Django)?
For example I declare the following static method

```
class SomeClass (object):
    @staticmethod
    def SomeStaticMethod (firstArg, **kwargs):  
        # do something
```

and in another class I want to use it like so

```
SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod ('first', second=2, third='three', fourth=4)
```

I tried to import, but got a NameError:global name 'SomeClass' is not defined

```
import myapp.SomeClass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> from somefile import SomeClass
>>> SomeClass.SomeStaticMethod('first', second=2, third='three')
first {'second': 2, 'third': 'three'}
```

It's also good to know that static methods are completely useless in most cases, since the module itself can be used as a namespace to the function. Thus:

```
def SomeStaticFunction(a, **kwargs):
    # do something
```

And:

```
>>> import somefile
>>> somefile.SomeStaticFunction(1, second=2, third='three')
1 {'second': 2, 'third': 'three'}
```